# Debugging why socket.on is not being hit

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

This issue is occurring on the client side of my application.
I am running into a issue with the socket.on event not being hit on my Node application. This usually happens when the site is being loaded for the first time by a client. When loading, the tabs usually have the data which has been dynamically generated in Javascript, however since the socket.on event is not being hit this content is not loading, leading to the tabs being blank (The base Pug/Jade file is still rendering - just no dynamic content). Refreshing the page usually fixes the issue and the sockets start receiving the data again.

There is no direct error message being output, the socket.on event is just not being hit. This also seems to solve itself once the page has been reloaded and is not occurring 100% of the time.

This is even more unusual, as when running my Node server in debug mode it is showing the socket.io-parser encoding the data and socket.io-client writing the data, meaning that it is being emitted, just not being picked up by the socket.on on my client side.

*Note that this has been simplified down*

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
    sendExampleData();
});
```

```
function sendExampleData() {
    mysqlFunc.getOrderData(function(rows){
        io.emit('example_data', rows);
    })
}
```

```
socket.on('example_data', function (rows) {
    console.log(rows);
}
```

I expect that on page load, the data is emitted and the socket.on event will receive this data, ready to be processed. Currently, although not happening every-time, socket.on is not being hit and the data is not being grabbed.

There is nothing out of the ordinary whilst running the server in Debugging mode and any ideas would be extremely helpful. If there's any other bits of information that would be useful in helping debug this issue please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Emitting : `io.emit('example_data')`, listening to : `socket.on('solvitt_data')`, normal?

Comment: Just me trying to simplify the code, edited now, apologies for that one!

Comment: The socket.io cheatscheet is very easy to understand. https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet Befor you emit a event (no matter if server or client) you should wait for the connection event.


Can you edit your question: Is this on the Server/Client side ?

Comment: Hi Marc and thanks for the reply. The issue is on the client side, with data not being rendered. I don't think the issue is with the emit event but with the on event. I'll edit the question to be more clear regarding the Server/Client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to figure out what the issue was.
My socket.on event listeners were inside my $(document).ready and were not being called on first page load. I'm assuming that the event listeners were not being defined early enough and therefore when I socket.emit'd on connection the event listeners had not actually loaded.

I moved all of the logic which was inside the $(document).ready out and moved my event listeners into a connection event (Thanks for the tip Marc).

```
socket.on('connect', function(){
    socket.on('data_1', funcOne);
    socket.on('data_2', funcTwo);
    socket.on('data_3', funcThree);
    socket.on('data_4', funcFour);
    socket.on('data_5', funcFive);
});
```

This fixed the issue and now socket.on is being hit every time on page load.
Thanks for the help guys and hopefully this can help someone also having this issue!